# C++ - Creating Basic Combat Function for Text RPG

Tags: c++, function

I am currently working on a basic text RPG for a class, and I am having some weird issues going on with the combat system. Basically, I have an option to attack or not to attack the enemy during each combat phase. When I attack the enemy, the health decreases at an expected rate. However, when I choose not to attack (which means that the enemy DOES attack still), the damage I do towards the enemy is not directly stated in that turn, but when I choose to attack the next time, it does the expected damage towards the enemy as well as the damage from when I supposedly did not attack.

(Warning: I know that my code will be poorly written and probably not with the best programming logic... I am a new student, and am just using what I have learned so far.)

### My code is as follows:

```
int showEnemyHp(int enemyhp, int attack) {
    enemyhp = enemyhp - attack;
    return enemyhp;
}

int showHp(int hp, int enemyattack) {
    hp = hp - enemyattack;
    return hp;
}

void enemyBattle() {
    int hp = 30, enemyhp = 20, attack = 10, enemyattack = 5;
    int hitEnemy;

    while (true) {
        cout << "Hit enemy?\n(1) Yes\n(2) No" << endl;
        cin >> hitEnemy;

        if (hitEnemy == 1) {
            enemyhp = showEnemyHp(enemyhp, attack);
            hp = showHp(hp, enemyattack);
            cout << "You hit the enemy." << endl;
            cout << "The enemy now has " << enemyhp << "HP left." << endl;
            if (enemyhp <= 0) {
                cout << "You've killed the enemy!" << endl;
                break;
            } else if (enemyhp > 0) {
                cout << "The enemy hits you back." << endl;
                cout << "You now have " << hp << "HP left." << endl;
            }
        } else if (hitEnemy == 2) {
            enemyHp = showEnemyHp(enemyhp, attack);
            hp = showHp(hp, enemyattack);
            cout << "You have chosen not to hit the enemy." << endl;
            cout << "The enemy hits you back." << endl;
            cout << "You now have " << hp << "HP left." << endl;
        } else {
            cout << "You can't do that!" << endl;
            return enemyBattle();
        }
    }
    while (hp > 0 && enemyhp > 0);
}
```

---

Can anybody help me with what I am doing wrong, and why that's happening? Also, any hints to fixing such an issue would be great. I would also appreciate possibly any help on how to better optimize this code. (Like I said, my toolbox for C++ is remarkbly limited right now. I am only about a month or so into studying it... my professor has yet to even teach us arrays, which I've learned about on my own). Thank you SO much for any help.

Comment: You have a call for `showEnemyHp()` in both cases so it’ll reduce the hp. It’s a very badly named function though since it doesn’t show anything and it has side effects you wouldn’t expect. Using a debugger would be very helpful here since you see exactly what the code does. I would suggest learning to use one vary early.

Comment: Thank you for your input. What sort of unexpected side effects can happen because of that? I will definitely take your advice on the debugger, appreciate the tip.

Comment: It’s a wanted side effect this time, meaning the health changes. But if someone is reading your code and sees “show enemy hp” they will assume it’ll just show it and not change it. So it has an unexpected side effect, and doesn’t have the actual effect since it doesn’t show anything. This is why naming functions etc is important. `attackEnemy` for example would convey much clearer intent for it. So it’s not anything happening without you knowing about, just a clarity issue.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Again, thanks!

Comment: Hi Cody, how are you writing your C++, within an IDE such as Visual Studio?  If you have the ability to put breakpoints into your code and step through code lines one by one during execution it can be helpful you in understanding logic and behavioural problems in your code.  Otherwise, what I tend to do is extract the code into a simple test function so I can play with inputs and outputs of the function, without having to run through the whole code again.  But keep going Cody, I am impressed by your motivation.

Comment: @Phill, I am writing it within a UNIX terminal that has a compiler built-in to where I access the terminal. I can definitely see your point though in terms of incremental testing my code, which is a habit I am still working on. I will look into IDEs more. Thank you for the compliment, Phill, as well as the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your overall logic seems to be fine except for a few details you may have not taken into account. Like  @Sami Kuhmonen mentioned in his comment, the `showEnemyHp()` function is actually updating the enemy's HP value and not displaying it.

It is better to rename the functions `int showEnemyHp(int, int)` and `int showHp(int, int)` to something more appropriate like `int updateEnemyHp(int, int)` and `int updateUserHp(int, int)`, if you plan on using them only for updating the HP values and nothing else.

Also, putting

`cout << "The enemy now has " << enemyhp << "HP left." << endl;`

before you check if enemy HP is negative can result in potentially unwanted negative values of HP to be printed (Assuming negative values of HP are not intended to be shown). It would be better to print HP values after you handle the extreme conditions.

```
cout << "You hit the enemy." << endl;
if (enemyhp <= 0) {
    cout << "You've killed the enemy!" << endl;
    break;
} else if (enemyhp > 0) {
    cout << "The enemy now has " << enemyhp << "HP left." << endl;
    cout << "The enemy hits you back." << endl;
    cout << "You now have " << hp << "HP left." << endl;
}
```

It should also be noted that the enemy's updated HP is not being displayed the when the user decides not to attack, so any damage done to the enemy during this round is not shown. So, simply adding the print for enemy HP can solve this issue

```
} else if (hitEnemy == 2) {
    enemyHp = showEnemyHp(enemyhp, attack);
    // Dammage done when user decides not to attack, probably should be commented?
    hp = showHp(hp, enemyattack);
    cout << "You have chosen not to hit the enemy." << endl;
    cout << "The enemy hits you back." << endl;
    cout << "You now have " << hp << "HP left." << endl;
    // Handle negative values of enemy HP and print final value
    if (enemyhp <= 0) {
        cout << "You've killed the enemy!" << endl;
        break;
    } else if (enemyhp > 0) {
        cout << "The enemy now has " << enemyhp << "HP left." << endl;
        cout << "The enemy hits you back." << endl;
        cout << "You now have " << hp << "HP left." << endl;
    }
}
```

In the final conditional branch which handles invalid inputs, calling the `enemyBattle()` during return can cause an infinite recursion, which is very very bad no matter the circumstance. It is better to replace `return enemyBattle();` with `continue;` which will simply continue the loop execution

```
} else {
    cout << "You can't do that!" << endl;
    // Continue program
    continue;
}
```

If you want the program to exit when the user enters an invalid input you can replace `return enemyBattle();` with `return;`, so your code will look like this:

```
} else {
    cout << "You can't do that!" << endl;
    // Exit program
    return;
}
```

It is also important to remember that the program is not checking the user's HP, in case the user's HP becomes zero or negative then the program might need to handle it by informing the user.

Lastly, I do not see the need for `while (hp > 0 && enemyhp > 0);` at the end of the program, it seems to be redundant since that statement will only be executed when the control leaves the `while(true){...}` loop which only happens when `enemyhp <= 0`.

Comment: I have to thank you for the in-depth explanation of everything. That clears up a ton of things for me. Thanks :)